# SearchController not searching custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9, uisearchbar

Not sure if the title makes to much sense so here is a description of what is going on:

I have a UITableViewController that is using a custom UITableViewCell for its data. I am then manually adding a searchBar to the header of the UITableView and setting it up based on this tutorial : http://useyourloaf.com

Now the searchBar is setup, it looks like it is working but the issue is that I am not actually getting any results and the table is not loading properly (the search results, it load the base data fine)

Here is my code for comparison. I know I must be missing something simple...

** I am hardcoding the data for my cells at the moment, this will change to a core data model once I can fix this issue... although this may be the base of my issue as I am hardcoding the cells at each IP **

```
@implementation CharitiesTableViewController{
NSArray *charities;
NSArray *searchResults;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setColors];

    [_charityTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CharityTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"charityCell"];

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 350.0;
//    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) setColors {

}

#pragma mark - Search Controller

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self searchForText:searchString];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [charities filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == _charityTable)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return [searchResults count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return SectionSpacer;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return SectionSpacer;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:{
            CharityTableViewCell *cell = (CharityTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"charityCell"];

            cell.charityImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cleanup"];
            cell.charityName.text = @"Garbage cleanup - Crowchild";
            cell.charityTagLine.text = @"City of Calgary";
            cell.charityDescriptionShort.text = @"We are rounding up anyone that wants to help clean up the grass and nearby areas close to crowchild.";

            return cell;
        }
        default:{
            UITableViewCell *cell;
            return cell;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You aren't initializing your `charities` array anywhere or putting any data in it so of course filtering it isn't going to give you any results.  Even if you did have data in it it wouldn't show up since you are putting hardcoded data in your table instead of using the `searchResults`

Comment: Yeah I figured that would be the case, so once I fetch the data properly do you think the code will work? Is it setup properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am silly.... I was trying to do this without initializing the data like a com mentor said. The code is correct and if anyone has any similar issues make sure your array of data actually has data in it...